clasp fails to push, even with "force" : 'A file with this name already exists in the current project
I've followed the repo's instructions to create a TS project. My first clasp push worked okay but after that I get this error (pasting in the first line, there's the whole huge request beneath it)
GaxiosError: A file with this name already exists in the current project: Code

Although at the end it says this:
└─ /Users/jonathantuzman/dev/personal/ev-chargers-appscript/appsscript.json
└─ /Users/jonathantuzman/dev/personal/ev-chargers-appscript/Code.js
└─ /Users/jonathantuzman/dev/personal/ev-chargers-appscript/Code.ts
Pushed 3 files.

I later noticed that the docs say "you can no longer edit your script at scripts.google.com" -- I had indeed done this in the middle of debugging so I thought maybe that was the problem, so I deleted my file on scripts.google.com, and I actually still get the same error!

Can I just add (as this result was the top search result on Google for the query clasp push force not working) that even though the last output line of the clasp push command states a successful message of: Pushed X files. where you think everything is fine, that you will want to fully inspect the whole output after your clasp push command. As I had been working with an app consisting of quite a few files the section immediately following my clasp push command was hidden and I missed the obvious errors! Hope this helps save someone an hour of headaches!

There are two files with the same name:
└─ /Users/jonathantuzman/dev/personal/ev-chargers-appscript/Code.js
└─ /Users/jonathantuzman/dev/personal/ev-chargers-appscript/Code.ts

Both refer to the same file. One is JavaScript, probably compiled  from typescript or pulled from main script project using clasp pull. Remove one of them after carefully checking the contents of the file:
rm /Users/jonathantuzman/dev/personal/ev-chargers-appscript/Code.js

To avoid mixing, use source folders like src/Code.ts and output folders like out/Code.js to separate compiled typescript, if you're compiling yourself. You should not use clasp pull.
